# ListBox throwing SelectedItems error on right click

Tags: c#, listbox, selecteditem, lync, lync-2010

Im working with Lync SDK and use a ContactSearchResultList (listBox) with `SelectionMode="Single"`.

But when I right click a item that is not selected the application crashes with the following stack-trace:

```
System.InvalidOperationException wurde nicht behandelt.
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=Can only change SelectedItems collection in multiple selection modes. Use SelectedItem in single select modes.
  Source=PresentationFramework
  StackTrace:
       bei System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.OnSelectedItemsCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
       bei System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
       bei System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.ClearItems()
       bei System.Windows.Controls.SelectedItemCollection.ClearItems()
       bei System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.Clear()
       bei Microsoft.Lync.Controls.UCListBoxItem.OnMouseRightButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
       bei System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseRightButtonDownThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
       bei System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
       bei System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
       bei System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
       bei System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
       bei System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
       bei System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseDownThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
       bei System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
       bei System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
       bei System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
       bei System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
       bei System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       bei System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
       bei System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
       bei System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
       bei System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
       bei System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
       bei System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
       bei System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       bei System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       bei MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       bei MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
       bei System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       bei MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       bei System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       bei MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       bei MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
       bei System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
       bei System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
       bei System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
       bei System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
       bei System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
       bei System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
       bei System.Windows.Application.Run()
       bei LyncPresenceBrowser.App.Main() in D:\_effexx\_Kunden\DFG\LyncPresenceBrowser\obj\x86\Debug\App.g.cs:Zeile 0.
       bei System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       bei System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       bei System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       bei System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Why is it throwing this error? At no point in my Code I am reffering to `SelectedItems`, I always use `SelectedItem`. Im stuck, please help me :)

//Heres the event:

```
public void contactSearchResultList1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (contactSearchResultList1.SelectedItem != null && contactSearchResultList1.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        expander1.IsEnabled = true;
        expander2.IsEnabled = true;
        expander1.IsExpanded = true;
        showGroupMembersWindow();
     }
     else
     {
        expander1.IsEnabled = false;
        expander2.IsEnabled = false;
        //closeGroupMembersWindow();
        //closeContactCardWindow();
     }
}
```

Comment: I cant find any property set to `Multi-Select`. I dont know what part of code of my application to show, because according to the stack-trace it seems like some default-behavior is throwing the exception. I commented all parts in my program related to `SelectedItem` and such, but the error is still appearing...

Comment: How about the OnMouse Click Event..? can you show that code..?

Comment: I dont know... I just use a SelectionChanged Event. I added the code to the Question.

Comment: can you add a check prior to the conditional check to see if the contactSearchResultList1.SelectedItem.Count ..?

Comment: try something like this `var count = (from item in contactSearchResultList1.Items where item.Selected select item).Count();`

Comment: That does not work. It displays "'Where' was not found. Give the type for the variable 'item'". (Im using german visual studio and dont know how to exactly translate the debug-error ;-))

Comment: are you using `System.Linq` in your using at the top of your code?

Comment: Yes I am using System.Linq. If you just want to get the number of selected Items, why not use `contactSearchResultList1.SelectedItems.Count`? The Application also seems to crash before it reaches the SelectionChanged event.

Comment: you should be able to get or check the number of selected Items and get a count.. that code works on my end not sure why it's not working on your end unless what you have is not a ListBox Item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the default value for `SelectionMode` on the `contactSearchResultList` is `Extended`. I changed that value and now everything seems to work...
Thanks for all the help!